# Converting an object array to valid JSON. for an ajax call

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I keep going around in circles trying to figure out why below keeps failing with error 'Unexpected end of JSON input' when taking an object array attempting to JSON.stringify and pass to an ajax call.

```
$(document).on("click", "#frmcomplist_cmdPrint", function(){
let complist = [];
let testlist = [];
let testnum = 0;

for(x = 1; x < rowCount; x++){
    thisuser = $('#username'+x).html();
    thiscomputer = $('#compname' +x).html();

    if(thisuser != '' || thiscomputer != ''){
        complist.push({
            user: thisuser,
            computer: thiscomputer
        });
    }
}

jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
        url: 'reports//complist_print.php',
         dataType: 'json',
         data: {functionname: 'computer_list', JSONList: JSON.stringify(complist)},
         success: function (obj, textstatus){
            if (!(obj.error == '')){
               jAlert(obj.error, 0 + 48, 'error', false);
            } else {

            }    
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error){
            //alert(xhr.responseText);
            jAlert(error, 0 + 16, "error", false);
         },
         complete: function (xhr, status) {
            // dumps error/result 
           console.log(xhr.responseText);            
        } 
});
});
```

Comment: But where is that error being thrown? Sure it's not in the response handling?

Comment: probably because `data` is not a valid JSON? Only one of the properties is a JSON string. Maybe JSON.stringify the whole object?

Comment: @adiga doesn't have to be json if OP is receiving as $_POST

Comment: @charlietfl okay. Don't know php

Comment: receiving here: $JSONList = (isset($_POST['JSONList']) ? $_POST['JSONList']: "");

Comment: The error is from the ajax response error: function ....  Unexpected end of JSON input

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  The code was actually working with the ajax POST just wasn't returning the information which it needed and this caused a false error.